# Using Ffidl with TCL to return pass-by-reference strings and arrays

Tags: pointers, dll, tcl

I've been using Ffidl to work with some devices that use the FTDI drivers, and for the most part it's all working fairly well.  I'm fairly certain that the area that I'm failing in comes from my lack of understanding of how TCL handles pointers behind the scenes.  In any case, I've gotten examples regarding functions that pass by reference to work by doing something like this:

```
::ffidl::callout rpbrd {pointer-var} int \
        [ffidl::symbol [ffidl::find-lib library] returns_pass_by_reference_double]
set dbl_ptr = [binary format [::ffidl::info format double] 1]
set my_int = [rpbrd dbl_ptr]
binary scan $dbl_ptr [::ffidl::info format double] my_dbl
puts $my_dbl
```

However, two things that I have not yet managed to figure out are return "by reference" strings (`char *`), because they always seem to return some junk data, whenever I try the above approach, as well as anything to do with arrays, because I don't even know where to begin to get those to work.  I'm pretty sure that the process behind the two would be similar, since one is an array of characters, and the other would just be an array of... well, something else.

Any help figuring this out would be much appreciated.  I've been working on it for days, and my Google-fu is failing when searching for any really good examples involving ffidl.

**Edit:** since the time of my post, I've managed, with some difficulty to get strings to work, using the `::ffidl::pointer-into-string` command.  Which basically just looks at the memory and copies bytes until it reaches a null point (I'm guessing).  This is not what I feel the optimum method should be, because this doesn't seem to work for by reference, since I can't pass the pointer by reference to a specific location in memory and just expect it to work without consequence. (If I'm not being clear, basically what I'd be doing is the equivalent of picking a random subaddress in my current block of memory and saying "Hmm, yep.  That seems like a good spot to just put some data." which is indeed a bad idea.)

I'm going to keep chugging along to attempt to figure out how to get arrays to work.  Starting with copying memory over and trying to work magic the bytes with some `binary scan`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tcl *really* likes to be able to manage the lifetime of its values itself, and it uses an immutable value model. (The reality is more complex, but program to the model, please!) Even if the value wasn't going to change, you'd still need to copy unless you could tell the generator of the data to use Tcl's own memory allocator, `Tcl_Alloc`, though there are a number of shortcuts available in the case where you are happy to copy (see `Tcl_SetResult` for example).

This means that the object passed in by reference really should be mapped to an abstract object (whose representation is an arbitrary name, such as `handle-12345`) and which has a number of operations on it which return information about the object represented by the handle; one such operation for your case would be to return a *copy* of a substring, another might be to return the overall length. The only mandatory operation is handling an explicit disposal of the handle.

I know this sounds all very clunky. It's just a natural consequence of a real impedance mismatch.

Comment: While this is useful in helping me understand how Tcl works "behind the scenes," I'm not sure just yet how I can use this to interpret Ffidl's pointer to a memory location into an array of, say, integers.

Not to say that this doesn't answer that, necessarily, just that I don't know how to apply it yet.

Comment: I don't quite know if my implementation really used what you were specifically talking about, but I do think that this helped me formulate my solution to some extent.  And for that, I thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of work, I finally came to the following [relatively anti-climactic] conclusion.  I figured that it would be appreciated for other people looking for this answer (if there ever is anyone) if I were to document my solution.  Anyways, from the beginning, with some C code, consider the function

```
void make_int_array(int*& out) {
    int* a = new int[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        a[i] = i+1;
    }
    out = a;
}
```

Essentially all this does is create a new array of `{1,2,3,4,5}` and use that for the out pointer.  Next, we'll write the Tcl wrapper:

```
::ffidl::callout _make_int_array {pointer-var} void \
                  [::ffidl::symbol ffidltest.dll make_int_array]
```

After that, you'll need to "cook" a few interfaces to use the make_int_array function.  You can do that like so:

```
proc make_int_array {} {
    set ints 5
    set intsize [::ffidl::info sizeof int]
    set bytesize [expr $intsize * $ints]

    set ptr [binary format [::ffidl::info format int] 1]
    _make_int_arrayptr ptr
    binary scan $ptr i ptr

    binary scan [::ffidl::peek $ptr $bytesize] \
                [::ffidl::info format int]$ints out
    return $out
}
```

There may be a much nicer way to do this, but this definitely worked and I'm happy for that.  However, if anyone has a nicer way, I'm still open to ideas.